# Google Maps Using Aurelia

Tags: javascript, google-maps, aurelia, jspm

I am using [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io), and I would like to render a basic map with Google Maps.

I tried Aurelia-Google-Maps (https://github.com/Vheissu/aurelia-google-maps), but just couldn't get it to work (everything was loading fine, but the `<google-map>` elements on my template were not rendered as a map).
I am now trying to use [Google-Map-API](https://github.com/Jam3/google-maps-api), so I can load everything just fine, create a Map object, but when I try to add properties, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

I do not at all see where my error comes.

Here's my code (accueil.js -- a controller)

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import mapsapi from 'google-maps-api';

@inject(mapsapi('myApiKey'))

export class Accueil {
    constructor(mapsapi) {
        mapsapi.then(function(maps) {
            var map = new maps.Map((document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}, // just random values
                zoom: 8
            })); // doesn't work
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you so much,

Comment: That question was a very long time ago, I honestly don't remember and do not have the project anymore. Ask a new question, maybe someone will have your answer.

Comment: ok and thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 5):

We've got a production site out running Aurelia with embedded Google Maps (https://farmtracksa.com) and are currently using our own component to manage embedding Google Maps in the page (and exposing the map via DI to the rest of our pages and components).

Our site is written up on TypeScript and our Google Maps control is broken up into a service and component, as follows:

```ts
import { autoinject } from "aurelia-framework";

@autoinject
export class GoogleMaps {
  constructor() {
    this.initialized = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.onInitialized = resolve;
      this.onInitializationFailed = reject;
    });
  }

  map: google.maps.Map = null;

  initialized: PromiseLike<void>;
  private onInitialized: () => void;
  private onInitializationFailed: (err: Error) => void;

  initialize(element: Element) {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, {});

    this.onInitialized();
  }
}
```

And the control, which you can embed in your view.

```ts
import {bindable, autoinject, inlineView, bindingMode, customElement, 
inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {DOM} from "aurelia-pal";

@inlineView("<template></template>")
@bindable({
  name: "zoom",
  changeHandler: "onZoomChanged",
  defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay,
  defaultValue: 17
})
@bindable({
  name: "latitude",
  changeHandler: "onCenterChanged",
  defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay,
  defaultValue: -34.1996316
})
@bindable({
  name: "longitude",
  changeHandler: "onCenterChanged",
  defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay,
  defaultValue: 19.0268722
})
@customElement("google-maps")
@inject(DOM.Element, GoogleMaps)
export class GoogleMapsControl {
  static map: google.maps.Map = null;

  constructor(private mapElement: Element, public googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {

  }

  bind() {

  }

  attached() {
    this.googleMaps.initialize(this.mapElement);

    this.googleMaps.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude));
    this.googleMaps.map.setZoom(this.zoom);
    this.onCenterChanged();
  }

  changing = false;

  zoom = 17;
  latitude = -34.1996316;
  longitude = 19.0268722;

  onZoomChanged() {
    this.googleMaps.map && this.googleMaps.map.setZoom(this.zoom);
  }

  onCenterChanged() {
    this.googleMaps.map && this.latitude && this.longitude && this.googleMaps.map.setCenter({ lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude });
  }
}
```

You'd then embed it in a view like this:

```html
<template>
  <require from="./google-maps"></require>

  <google-maps zoom="7"></google-maps>
</template>
```

Finally, you'll also need to make sure that you're loading the Google Maps API into your web app. I accomplished this by placing the following snippet (from the [Google Maps Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)) in my `index.html` file since I was using maps throughout my application.

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

You'll want to make sure that the Google Maps script has been loaded before you attempt to initialize a `GoogleMaps` element on your page, failure to do so will result in errors in your dev console.

Comment: Where did you set the maps api key?

Comment: Ah, sorry for not including that - I am still loading the standard Google Maps library using the provided code snippet from Google - all this does is wrap the library in an Aurelia friendly API.

Comment: That requires

`typings install dt~google.maps --global`

and a reference to the service in the control:

`import {GoogleMaps} from "./googleMapsService";`

Comment: I am getting this error: `Uncaught Wc {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Wc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…my_api_key_here&callback=initMap:137:73"}`
removed the call back from this url and it loads blank.

Comment: I do see tons of html embedded in my page though.

Comment: Sorry about that, well spotted, fixing the answer now - it should be:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>`

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminPannell for your example, super useful. Funny thing is, even though the element appears on the page source, for some obscure to me reason, is rendered on a tiny 1x1px region! Did you have to apply some styling to make it take up the entire page height/width?

Comment: That's correct, you probably need to set `display: block` on your `google-maps` element type in CSS.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminPannell, I did experiment with `display` but the only thing that worked was to override `position` : `position: inherit !important;`. I cringe every time I use `!important` but otherwise, the component refused to appear.

Answer (score 3):

One issue I can see straight up is you are trying to add in your Google Map from within the `constructor` function which is mostly run before the DOM has properly loaded and ready to run scripts.

Try moving your code into the `attached` method which gets fired when the DOM is ready to be mutated instead:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import mapsapi from 'google-maps-api';

@inject(mapsapi('myApiKey'))

export class Accueil {
    mapsapi;

    constructor(mapsapi) {
        this.mapsapi = mapsapi;
    }

    attached() {
        this.mapsapi.then(function(maps) {
            var map = new maps.Map((document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes just after posting this question I tried what you proposed, but it still didn't work (same error). I'll keep looking. For the moment I just used an `iframe` with a regular HTML page.

Comment: @Dwayne's approach has to work. There's no other way. That's how I'm doing it and it works every time. My proposition is to try to debug the code. Put `document.getElementById('map')` result into a variable, set a breakpoint after it and check if it's not `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Also - try to preserve the `map` variable. Namely - set it as `Accueil` field. Maybe reference is getting GCed and that's why map isn't loading?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

- Accueil.js

  ```
  import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
  import mapsapi from 'google-maps-api';

  @inject(mapsapi('your-key'))

  export class Accueil{
    constructor(mapsapi) {
       this.mapsLoadingPromise = mapsapi.then(maps =>{
         this.maps = maps;
       })
    }

    attached() {
        this.mapsLoadingPromise.then(() =>{
            new this.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
               center: {lat: 39.8282, lng: -98.5795},
               zoom:   15
         });
      });
    }
  }
  ```
- Accueil.html

  ```
  <template>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </template>
  ```

Comment: Don't forget to add a height and width to your container.